# Print count from total integer

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax call. The ajax will be returning an integer value for eg: 4 and i need to append star images string based on the integer return. For example if ajax return an integer of 4, so i need to append 4 times star image string from an asset folder. I know that i can use loop but is there any simplifier method that can just repeat from the integer and append the image string based on integer count. Thanks

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'https://test.com/WebAPI/getItemRating?moduleid=video&itemid='+elem[col]['videoid'],
data: {},
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
    var count = Math.round(data);
    var starsArr = "";

    // Before this i used loop
    //$.each(data, functn (i, element) {
    //    starsArr += "&nbsp;<img alt='star' src='/videoAssets/Galeri Video/img/star.png'/>";
    //});

    return starsArr;
   }
});
```

Comment: Returning a value from the success function doesn't do anything. AJAX is asynchronous.

Comment: I don't think there's any simple shortcut for the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Then i just stick with the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `$.each()`, though. That's for looping over an array or object, but you just have a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array with multiple copies of the string. Then you can slice the array and join them to concatenate them into a new string.

```js
var stars = Array(5).fill("<img alt='star' src='/videoAssets/Galeri Video/img/star.png'/>");

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://test.com/WebAPI/getItemRating?moduleid=video&itemid=' + elem[col]['videoid'],
  data: {},
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    var count = Math.round(data);
    var starsHTML = stars.slice(0, count).join("&nbsp;");
    $("#stars").html(starsHTML);
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually, this is what i'm looking for.Thanks again